# The meaning of 石松 in 待ってください用心棒なら この石松が

Tags: meaning

I am looking for the meaning of 石松 in this context (待ってください用心棒なら この石松が) but I cannot find it anywhere. Also, this sentence is one that was interrupted, hence the abrupt "が".

Comment: 石松 is the speaker's name. He's offering his service as a 用心棒

Comment: By137, you should make that in to an answer, since it is, you know, the answer to Amish's question.

Comment: Yeah, but I always try to write thorough answers and I couldn't think of a way to flesh this out, so I was hesitant. But I guess as long as it answers the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

石松 is the speaker's name. He's offering his service as a 用心棒.

You said he got cut off, so the sentence could have ended something like

待ってください用心棒なら この石松が**やります** or **つとめます**。
Or, if he is using 敬語、
待ってください用心棒なら この石松が**致します**

There are hundreds of possibilties, so these are just some examples